# UI Widget drawing in order

Tags: c++

I have a custom UI Widget library I've created for a game I'm working on. I need to consider drawing order and retro fit it into what I currently have and not sure of the best way to do so. I have a UI class which loads the widgets from an xml file. It stores all widgets in a map where the key is the string name of the widget.

Widgets can hold other Widgets in a parent child relationship (so the Widget class has a map of Widgets where the name is the key again). When I draw I loop through the UI widget map and only call the Widget's Draw() function's that don't have parents (most top level). Within each Widget's Draw() it loops through it's children and calls their Draw() functions.

The question is what would be a good way to have a sort order variable for each widget work with drawing in the order of the sort order variable while keeping the maps, since I like the ease of finding widgets by the string key name?

Any ideas?

Comment: A `map` for easy access of the widgets by name, and a sorted `vector` (or `list`) for drawing?

Comment: Is that pretty common? It's not considered a waste of space to store them both? I know they are pointers but it still takes up storage space right?

Comment: I don't have personal experience, but that's what I would do. And unless you have millions of widgets it's not going to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need multiple ways to order the same set of items, you have two choices:

- Store both orderings, or
- Store one ordering, and figure out the other one on the fly

Storing the second set of orderings is a way to pay with memory to save CPU cycles.

In your case, you have two orderings: the one implemented by the name-to-widget map, and the one for the drawing order. You have three implementation choices:

- **Store widgets in the map (i.e. ordered by name), and run a topological sort each time you need to figure out the drawing order** - I assume here that the reason to order for drawing is to make sure that parents are drawn before children, implying the topological sort.
- **Store widgets in a list by the drawing order, and run linear lookups to get widgets by their name** - This may be a good option when you draw widgets a lot, but look up by name very infrequently.
- **Store widgets in the map (i.e. ordered by name), and make a separate list of either widgets or widget names, arranged according to the drawing order** - This double-accounting spends memory to buy back the CPU cycles that you would otherwise waste for re-ordering in the drawing order.